# how to Add ArrayList in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I got a problem when insert an `ArrayList` into `ArrayList`.

My source code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
          ArrayList<String> mentah = new ArrayList<String>();

          mentah.add("Reza");
          mentah.add("Fata");
          mentah.add("Faldy");
          mentah.add("Helsan");
          mentah.add("Dimas");
          mentah.add("Mamun");
          mentah.add("Erik");
          mentah.add("Babeh");
          mentah.add("Tio");
          mentah.add("Mamang");

          ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result =new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

          result.add(mentah);   
    }
}
```

How can I create a list based on that data; that will look like:

```
[[data1,data2,data3],[data4,data5,data6],[data7,data8,data9,data10]]
```

10 div 3 is 3 (so 3 elements per sublist)

10 mod 3 is 1 (so last sublist has 4 entries)

10 divide by 3 is 
3 3 4

Comment: use  this line   `result.addAll(mentah);`  to add ArrayList into ArrayList.

Comment: I think you have to  do all that manually - first calculate count of normal elements, and in cycle create a new list for each element, and put that list in the upper list. Then put the last extended element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upgraded the answer of @Narayana Ganesh:

```
ArrayList<String> mentah = new ArrayList<String>();
mentah.add("Reza");
mentah.add("Fata");
mentah.add("Faldy");
mentah.add("Helsan");
mentah.add("Dimas");
mentah.add("Mamun");
mentah.add("Erik");
mentah.add("Babeh");
mentah.add("Tio");
mentah.add("Mamang");

List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

for (int j= 0; j< mentah.size() ; j+=3) {
    int end = mentah.size() <= j+2 ? mentah.size() : j+3;
    if(mentah.size() - j == 4) end = end +1;
    if(j != 9) result.add(mentah.subList(j, end));
}
    System.out.println(result);  
}
```

**Result:**
 `[[Reza, Fata, Faldy], [Helsan, Dimas, Mamun], [Erik, Babeh, Tio, Mamang]]`

Comment: Dont get me wrong; but this code really really hard to read. But well, it did the job, did it. But well, awfully inflexible; and well, just bad.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution would look like:

```
List<String> allNames = Arrays.asList("Reza", "Fata", ...
List<List<String>> slicedNames = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> sublist = new ArrayList<>();
int sublistTargetLength = 3;

for (String name : allNames) { 
  sublist.add(name);
  if (sublist.size() == sublistTargetLength) {
    slicedNames.add(sublist);
    sublist = new ArrayList<>();
  }    
}
if (sublist.size() > 0) {
  slicedNames.get(slicedNames.size()-1).addAll(sublist);
}
```

Some notes:

- The above iterates your initial list of names (which can created using that single call to Arrays.asList()); and puts the entries into same-sized lists; which are then added to the slicedNames list of list.
- If there is any "remaining" data; that is simply added to the last element of the list of list.
- You should prefer to use the interface type List for your variable types; you only use the specific implementation class (ArrayList) when instantiating the list
- When iterating anything, prefer the for-each looping style when possible

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can achieve this using subList method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> mentah = new ArrayList<String>();

        mentah.add("Reza");
        mentah.add("Fata");
        mentah.add("Faldy");
        mentah.add("Helsan");
        mentah.add("Dimas");
        mentah.add("Mamun");
        mentah.add("Erik");
        mentah.add("Babeh");
        mentah.add("Tio");
        mentah.add("Mamang");

        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        for (int j= 0; j< mentah.size() ; j+=3) {
            int end = mentah.size() <= j+2 ? mentah.size() : j+3;
            result.add(mentah.subList(j, end));
        }

        for (List<String> item : result) {
            System.out.println(" - -"+item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create sublists with a maximal size of 3 which will give you something like this

```
[[Reza, Fata, Faldy], [Helsan, Dimas, Mamun], [Erik, Babeh, Tio], [Mamang]]
```

then check if the last sublist size is less than 3 if yes add this to the second last sublist and remove the last one

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> mentah = new ArrayList<>();
        mentah.add("Reza");
        mentah.add("Fata");
        mentah.add("Faldy");
        mentah.add("Helsan");
        mentah.add("Dimas");
        mentah.add("Mamun");
        mentah.add("Erik");
        mentah.add("Babeh");
        mentah.add("Tio");
        mentah.add("Mamang");

        List<List<String>> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        int sizeOfOriginalList = mentah.size();
        int sizeOfSubLists = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfOriginalList; i += sizeOfSubLists) {
            parts.add(new ArrayList<>(mentah.subList(i, Math.min(sizeOfOriginalList, i + sizeOfSubLists))));                
        }
        if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).size()<sizeOfSubLists){
            parts.get(parts.size()-2).addAll(parts.get(parts.size()-1));
            parts.remove(parts.get(parts.size()-1));
        }
        System.out.println(parts);
    }        
}
```